# How to transfer the file from Windows Form Application to Xamarin Forms using USB cable C#.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, xamarin.forms

I am now developing Android Application and the Windows Form.

In the previous, the users need to plug in with USB, copy the file and paste into android folder but it would be troublesome and takes time to do.

How can I transfer the file directly from the PC to android Folder (Internal Storage/ downloads) ?

I tried with FolderBrowserDialog to browse and copy into android but "OK" button is disabled when I point the location. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrFE6.png)

Should I write it in Windows Form backend or Xamarin Forms backend side in order to direct transfer into the Android App?

I cannot use Web API as cannot use the internet connection.

```
FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
                
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
         txtCopy.Text = dialog.SelectedPath;
   }
         string copyFileName = Path.Combine(txtCopy.Text, originalFile); //originalFile->FileName (testing.jpg)

         File.Copy(txtFile1.Text, copyFileName, true);
```

Direct file transfer from Windows Form and Xamarin Forms by clicking button

Comment: CIFS, ftp, scp, custom server, etc.  There are many ways you could do this.  Which you pick depends on your requirements

Comment: Perhaps you could work something via Bluetooth.  Otherwise, something like Jason has suggested, maybe using something like dropbox or google drive might be the way.  Or maybe a webservice that serves these files for the android app to request

Comment: Thank you for answering. I know how to transfer the data by using Web API but do not have internet access. Only method is transferring file via USB cable. Sadly, I still cannot find how to transfer directly by clicking button instead of drag and drop the files.

Comment: I for one am still not really 100% sure what the problem is here.  Once the device is plugged in and all the PC/Device trusts etc are set, From the PC perspective it's just like any other storage device.  Does this work if you skip the FolderBrowserDialog and copy to a hardcoded path?

Comment: This is an Android emulator running on the PC, with USB plugged into PC? So your problem is how to transfer between host PC and emulator's storage?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it is real physical android device plugging in to PC. My problem here is I do not want to transfer the file from PC to Android internal storage device by Drag and Drop. Just Click the button and auto copy from PC to Android or Android to PC.

Comment: @Hursey it does not work by using "FolderBrowserDialog" to get the folder path of Android Device Folder. 

The problem is transferring the file from PC to Android without drag and drop by the users. Just transfer automatically behind the backend.

Comment: You've not actually answered the earlier question.  If you attempt to copy the file to the device via a hard coded path rather than selecting it via the FolderBrowserDialog, does that work?

Comment: Please look at the below answer bro. I am using MediaDevices in NuGet Package Manager. I can transfer the file from Android to PC but I cannot transfer the file from PC to Android. Please help if you know how to do it. Thanks. @Hursey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too had issues with copying to/from Android with Xamarin.  Originally directed to use ADB.exe (Android Debug Bridge), but that had too many security holes / issues and was restricted from using that.  Could not use generic 3rd party for other reasons and had to write my own Android / Xamarin file transfer library (works great).  One thing I found in MY research was what was the naming convention for paths did not always match what you think it might / should.  For example, your "Internal shared storage" wasn't really that when I connected.

```
"DT50\Internal shared storage\Download"
```

it was just

```
"Internal Storage\Download".
```

Did not have a leading \ character and it worked. Writing to other directories, you need to prompt/grant permission on the Xamarin side to look at SOME possible other working folder directories, but that might be something for you at another time.

Comment: Correct @DRapp. Now I can solve the problem. No need to add device name in front of the folder path. I updated already in the source code in here. Thanks.

Comment: @DANIELKT, if this worked, be sure to click checkbox next to answer so others in the future know what DID work and resolve the issue.  Also, up-tic on answers here and in future that you find helpful on other things you encounter.  Also an indicator of others that ...hey, this worked for me too

Comment: Ok.. @DRapp, sure. Please mark my answers in the above too. I already modified source code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I made a Windows Form project to complete the copy.

You could refer to the following code:

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void folderBrowserDialog1_HelpRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = dialog.SelectedPath;
            }
            
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            dialog.ShowDialog();
            textBox2.Text = dialog.SelectedPath;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DirectoryInfo thefolder = new DirectoryInfo(textBox1.Text);
            foreach (FileInfo nextfile in thefolder.GetFiles()) 
            {
                try
                {
                    string filename = nextfile.Name;
                    string filefullname = nextfile.FullName;
                    string mudi = textBox2.Text + "\\" + filename;
                    if (File.Exists(mudi))
                    {
                        //File.Delete(mudi);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        File.Copy(filefullname, mudi);
                        MessageBox.Show("Successful");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I already used the FolderBrowserDialog but the thing is when I tried to click the folder under the Android Device (eg. "Samsung/Internal Shared Storage/ downloads), I cannot click "OK" in folderDialog to get the folder path." 

Every folder path can select and click "OK" except the folder under Android device folder.

Answer (score 0):

Now I got it. I have to download MediaDevices framework in NuGet Package Manager to download/ transfer the file from Android device to PC.

I can transfer the file from Android to PC.

But the thing is I cannot transfer/ Upload the file from PC to Android (when using PCToPDA()). When I run the program, the error Director "DT50\Internal shared storage\Download" not found appear even though the directory path is correct.

Any idea why is that happening?
[image]

[image]

**Updated One**

The problem has been solved. Instead of writing "DT50\Internal shared storage\Download", I have to remove DT50 and just "\Internal shared storage\Download". Commented the wrong one and Updated the correct the source code below.

```
    string originalFile;

    private void BtnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Browse();     //Get the files from Android Folder
    }

    private void Browse()
    {
        try
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtFile1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                string fileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                originalFile = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Browse-ERR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void BtnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PDAToPC();       //Android to PC
        //PCToPDA();       //PC to Android 
    }

    private void PDAToPC()
    {
        try
        {
            string DeviceNameAsSeenInMyComputer = "DT50";

            var devices = MediaDevice.GetDevices();

            using (var device = devices.Where(d => d.FriendlyName == DeviceNameAsSeenInMyComputer || d.Description == DeviceNameAsSeenInMyComputer).First())
            {
                device.Connect();
                var photoDir = device.GetDirectoryInfo(@"\Internal shared storage\Download");
                var files = photoDir.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

                
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    string destinationFileName = $@"D:\KhineThein\Testing\TransferTesting\photo\{file.Name}";
                    if (!File.Exists(destinationFileName))
                    {
                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(destinationFileName, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
                        {
                            device.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fs);
                            
                        }
                    }


                }
                device.Disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "PDAToPC-ERR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void PCToPDA()
    {
        try
        {
            string DeviceNameAsSeenInMyComputer = "DT50";
            string tempFileName = "CaptureImport.txt";
            var devices = MediaDevice.GetDevices();

            using (var device = devices.Where(d => d.FriendlyName == DeviceNameAsSeenInMyComputer || d.Description == DeviceNameAsSeenInMyComputer).First())
            {
                device.Connect();
                var photoDir = device.GetDirectoryInfo(@"\Internal shared storage\Download");
                var files = photoDir.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    string originalFileName = $@"D:\KhineThein\Testing\TransferTesting\photo\{tempFileName}";

                    //string transferToFileName = $@"{DeviceNameAsSeenInMyComputer}\Internal shared storage\Download\{tempFileName}";
                   string transferToFileName = $@"\Internal shared storage\Download\{tempFileName}";

                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(originalFileName, FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        //device.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fs);                       //Path, Stream
                        device.UploadFile(fs, transferToFileName);                      //Stream, Path
                    }


                }
                device.Disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "PCToPDA-ERR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```